# manipulation on a file - vb.net plus some regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

The below is the content of my file(which is already sorted). Whichever is there between square brackets, relate to one transaction. The transactions can be groupa, groupb,groupc etc.

```
Jan 2012 02:10:12 [5678](groupa):Part 1:data1
Jan 2012 02:10:12 [5678](groupa):Part 2:data2
Jan 2012 02:10:12 [5678](groupa):Part 3:data3
Jan 2012 02:10:12 [5678](groupa):Part 4:data4
Jan 2012 02:13:14 [12308](groupa):Part 1:data1
Jan 2012 02:13:14 [12308](groupa):Part 2:data2
Jan 2012 02:13:24 [34517](groupb):Part 1:data1
Jan 2012 02:13:24 [34517](groupb):Part 2:data2
```

I want to output the below data to another file using vb.net. It should contain the transaction group, followed by the time(the time should be taken from the first row of the contents grouped by transaction, then grouped by the number inside the square bracket, in the contents). Next line should concatenate the data(after Part [1-9]:), corresponding to the particular transaction grouped by the number inside the square bracket. For the above contents,

```
groupa at Jan 2012 02:10:12
data1data2data3data4
groupa at Jan 2012 02:13:14
data1data2
groupb at Jan 2012 02:13:24
data1data2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first let's create a class to represent that data. It will make it easier to work it. Here is what mine looks like:

```
Public Class LogEntry
    Public Property DateTime As DateTime
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Group As String
    Public Property Part As String
    Public Property Data As String
End Class
```

Now that we have that, let's parse each line with a regular expression. They aren't my strength, but in this case it works:

```
Dim text = File.ReadAllLines("log.log")
Dim rx As New Regex("^(?<date>.+)\s\[(?<id>\d+)\]\((?<group>.+)\):(?<part>.+):(?<data>.+)$")
Dim logEntries As New List(Of LogEntry)
For Each line In text
    Dim match = rx.Match(line)
    Dim entry As New LogEntry With _
        {
            .DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups("date").Value, "MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
            .Id = Int32.Parse(match.Groups("id").Value),
            .Group = match.Groups("group").Value.Trim(),
            .Part = match.Groups("part").Value.Trim(),
            .Data = match.Groups("data").Value.Trim()
        }
    logEntries.Add(entry)
Next
```

Here we are loading the text from a file. It doens't matter how it gets the text. After that we iterate over each line and gather the information with a regular expression. Once we parse it, we create a `LogEntry` and add it to a list. As a list this will make it easier to work. We can use LINQ to group, then print it out:

```
Dim grouped = logEntries _
.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key .Id = x.Id, Key .Group = x.Group, Key .DateTime = x.DateTime}) _
.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key.DateTime)

For Each group In grouped
    Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1:MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss}", group.Key.Group, group.Key.DateTime)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", group.Select(Function(x) x.Data)))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.dont we need get and set methods for public property?I tried using Public Group As String instead of Public Property Group As String and similarly for other members. But not sure, if it is because of that, got a "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[errorfileprocessor.LogEntry,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'." error at Console.writeline(string.join

Comment: @Maneesh - I am using VB 11; which has [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx). What version of Visual Studio / VB.NET are you compiling with?

Comment: That error is gone, if we use ToArray function in visual studio 2008. Thanks a lot